# react axios и jwt авторизация. Не отправляется headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt, авторизация

1. Сначала получаю token от сервера и записываю его в sessionStorage

```
export const AuthApi = {
  async auth(username, password) {
    const response = await instance.post("api-token-auth/", {username: username, password: password});
    if (response.status === 200) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
      return response;
    }
  }
}
```

2. Забираю token из sessionStorage и прикрепляю к headers:

```
export const UsersApi = {
  async getUsers() {
    const token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    const response = await axios.get("http://emphasoft-test-assignment.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/", {headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }});
    return response
  }
}
```

3. Сервер возвращает такую ошибку:

```
detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

Перепробовал и одинарные кавычки для Authorization и двойные. Пробовал отправлять как Bearer, так и без него. Также отправлял Bearer JWT - ничего не привело к результату...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте `console.log(token)` после `getItem`.
Нужно понять, нету токена, или он шлется неправильно.

Если нет токена, смотрите порядок/причины вызова `auth`/`getUsers`.

Comment: Большое спасибо). Токен точно приходит. Я вижу его в консоли. Вижу его в localStorage, если сохраняю туда, а не в sessionStorage. (то есть 100% что он есть)

Если открыть панель разработчика - в network я вижу в Request Headers свой "Authorization": "Bearer 781bd9f1de084f4daa7ba2aa8a71a2eab855354e"

Может ли быть такое, что сервер настроен на другой заголовок и ждёт, что я отправлю токен не в "Authorization", а в каком-то другом ключе? На ваш взгляд?)

Comment: Это уже документацию на api/v1 надо смотреть

Comment: Вам ее или дали вместе с assignment-ом, или ждут что бы угадаете, или что спросите.

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: Всегда рад; можете даже "принять ответ"